# How do you mix junit5 and junit4 for the sake of PowerMockito?

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, junit5, powermockito

I'm using junit5, but I am in dire need to mock some static methods and constructors, etc. Since Powermockito only works with Junit4, I need to mix junit4 and junit5. Can someone explain how to do something like that? For example, what would I need to modify in this test case skeleton?

```
package com.mypackage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClass {

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    void testRequestHandling() throws Exception {
         ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix JUnit 4 and 5 in a single project, see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/main/junit5-multiple-engines for how to set that up.

What you can *not* do is mix JUnit 4 mechanisms into JUnit 5 (Jupiter) tests. That means that you have to use JUnit 4 tests when using Powermock - since that doesn’t work with Jupiter - but are free to use Jupiter tests for everything else, including plain Mockito.

Comment: Do I need to add additional dependencies for junit4 or does adding junit5 dependency automatically take care of it?

Comment: It’s all in the linked project

Comment: In the gradle file there is this:     val junit4Version = "4.13"

Comment: However, junit5 includes junit4 already (the legacy engine) so why I need to specify junit4 in the depencency again?

Comment: It's not working for me. The test cases just aren't being run

Comment: You checked out the sample project, tried `./gradlew test` and what happened next?

Comment: And no, junit5 does not automatically include junit4 (Vintage) you have to explicitly include it in the dependencies. Just the way it's done in https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/main/junit5-multiple-engines/build.gradle.kts#L30-L34